# Why distinct is not taking WHERE condition in Cosmos?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Why [distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/keywords#distinct) is not taking considering WHERE clause? I am getting all records and I want only those which satisfies WHERE conditon.

Query:

```
SELECT distinct c.id, c.stockNumber, c.createdDateTime, c.lineItems 
FROM c
JOIN t IN c.lineItems
WHERE c.stockNumber in ('123')
and t.operationId = 1400742
```

Expected Result:

```
{
  "id": "b3d7768e-7a22-4109-9511-cdd17585267b",
  "createdDateTime": "2023-06-01T21:02:34.4800722+00:00",
  "earliestPaymentDate": "2023-05-31T07:00:00+00:00",
  "stockNumber": "123",
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "itemUpdateDateTime": "2023-06-01T21:07:26.2846163+00:00",
      "location": "SomeLocation",
      "operationId": 1400742
    }
  ]
}
```

Actual Result:

```
[
   {
  "id": "b3d7768e-7a22-4109-9511-cdd17585267b",
  "createdDateTime": "2023-06-01T21:02:34.4800722+00:00",
  "earliestPaymentDate": "2023-05-31T07:00:00+00:00",
  "stockNumber": "123",
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "itemUpdateDateTime": "2023-06-01T21:07:26.2846163+00:00",
      "location": "SomeLocation",
      "operationId": 1400742
    },
    {
      "itemUpdateDateTime": "2023-06-01T21:07:26.28473+00:00",
      "location": "SomeLocation",
      "operationId": 1400741
    },
    {
      "itemUpdateDateTime": "2023-06-01T21:07:26.284864+00:00",
      "location": "SomeLocation",
      "operationId": 1400741
    },
    {
      "itemUpdateDateTime": "2023-06-01T21:07:26.284906+00:00",
      "location": null,
      "operationId": null
    },
    {
      "itemUpdateDateTime": "2023-06-01T21:07:26.2849904+00:00",
      "location": null,
      "operationId": null
    }
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not because of the distinct keyword. The code you provided selects the field `c.lineitem` and filter is on `t.operationId`. That is the reason you are getting all the data from `lineitems` array.  Below is the corrected code.

**Code:**

```
SELECT  distinct c.id, c.stockNumber, c.createdDateTime,
{"operationId":t.operationId,"location":t.location,"itemUpdateDateTime": t.itemUpdateDateTime} as lineItems
FROM c
JOIN t IN c.lineItems
WHERE c.stockNumber in ('123')
and t.operationId =  1400742
```

The above code selects the `id`, `stockNumber`, and `createdDateTime` fields from the root document `c`, and creates a new `lineItems` object that includes only the `operationId`, `location`, and `itemUpdateDateTime` fields from the `lineItems` array using the `JOIN` operator.

[image]

**Updated code:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.stockNumber, c.createdDateTime, 
t as lineItems FROM c JOIN t IN c.lineItems
WHERE c.stockNumber in ('123') and t.operationId = 1400742
```

Comment: Thank you for this clarification and answer. What if `lineItems` grows tomorrow? Do I need to declare all values like this? Right now, it has 3 values but let's say down the road, this object contains 15-20 fields.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.stockNumber, c.createdDateTime, t as lineItems
FROM c
JOIN t IN c.lineItems
WHERE c.stockNumber in ('123')
and t.operationId = 1400742`

Comment: Ah ha! so basically, I had to remove `c.lineItems` and update it with `t as c.lineItems` from my original query which I pasted in question above. Thanks again